# Определения города находжения юзера?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать check geo postion где город выводить на русском языке
Пример запроса я прикрепил

```
fetch('https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=test')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then(data =>  console.log(data.region))
```

Comment: нужно либо связаться с поддержкой, либо локализовывать самому. В бесплатной версии возможно такая функциональность отсутствует

Comment: локализировать самому как можно ?

Comment: вам надо английский на русский перевести? ну можно послать еще один запрос `https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=Moscow` и распарсить страничку :)

Comment: а есть адекватный вариант ? ))

Comment: @babakov.roman678 - скачать список городов мира, перевести через переводчика, оформить в виде словаря/ассоциативного массива, и если город отсутствует в таблице - переводить с помощью транслити - так устроит? - дешево и сердито

Comment: не вариант, думайте думать более проще

Comment: @babakov.roman678, самый простой вариант - делать свой словарь с ключом на английском и значением на русском

Comment: @Zhihar, зачем парсить html, если есть `api`?

Comment: Grundy можете показать кодом как парсить api в ru Город. Ибо я не разобрался

Comment: @babakov.roman678, никак. Из апи приходит только английский город, следовательно на твоей стороне должен быть словарь, сопоставляющий английское название и русское. Либо можешь попробовать обратиться к поддержке и возможно в платных версиях, есть возможность локализации